# DRF Reverse Relationship Unable to Filter in Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Having an interesting problem with DRF and wondering if anyone has any ideas.

For a simplified example, take these two Django models:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user_who_voted = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.IntegerField(choices = [(-1, "down"), (1, "up")])
    timestamp_voted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    sample_model = models.ForeignKey('SampleModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'sample_model_votes')
    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user_who_voted', 'sample_model_id'], name='one_vote_pp_sample_model')]

class SampleModel (models.Model):
    #does some stuff
```

In serializing SampleModel, I want to be able to get the value for `vote` for the request user (of which there is guaranteed to only be one vote, if any).

In a Django shell, I can pull an instance/item of SampleModel easily:

```
samplemodelexample = SampleModel.objects.get(pk = 1)
```

and then I can traverse the reverse relationship to `Vote` successfully to return the `vote` value:

```
samplemodelexample.sample_motel_votes.filter(user_who_voted_id = 1).get().vote
```

Taking this exact same code (simplified to show relevant portions) into DRF seems to create an issue:

```
class SampleModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_vote = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = ['user_vote']
        read_only_fields = fields
    def get_user_vote(self, obj):
        try:
            vote = obj.sample_model_votes.filter(user_who_voted == self.context['request'].user).get().vote #stacktrace on this line
            return f"{vote}"
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return '0'
```

I get an error on the line indicated that `NameError: name 'user_who_voted' is not defined`

Does anyone have any idea why?

As some additional background: in practice, there would of course be many users and many votes, but if I put just one vote in the `Vote` table, then substituting the line generating the error in `SampleModelSerializer` with

```
vote = obj.sample_model_votes.first().vote
```

returns the correct value for `vote`.
In summary, this seems to be an issue with `.filter()` in DRF.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two of `=` in your query. You should have one only:

```
obj.sample_model_votes.filter(user_who_voted=self.context['request'].user).get().vote
```

Because you used two, Python is thinking it is comparison and evaluating `user_who_voted` as a variable. Since you don't have that variable, you have this error.

Comment: I am beyond a moron-- just a typo on my part that I missed despite looking a thousand times. Really sitting here thinking something was broken with DRF. Thanks!

Comment: Happens to the best of us